# What is the $\mathbb E[(X-\mu)g(X)]$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

What is the $\mathbb E[(X-\mu)g(X)]$?

Let $X\sim N(\mu , \sigma ^2)$ and $g:R \Rightarrow R$ and $g$ is bounded and differentiable.

I need to show $E[(X-\mu)g(X)]=\sigma ^2 \mathbb E[g'(X)]$

**My attempt**

I don't know if I can split the expectations into 2, are they independent? Well I assumed I could.

I got $\mathbb E[(X-\mu)g(X)]=\mathbb E[(X-\mu)\mathbb Eg(X)$

Then I know that $\mathbb E[(X-\mu)=\mathbb E[X]-\mathbb E[\mu]=0$

This shows that infact, they can't be independent and I'm not sure why.

Then I can rewrite $\mathbb E[(X-\mu)g(X)]=\mathbb E[Xg(x)]-\mathbb E[\mu g(X)]$

I attmpted to use integration by parts, but I can't see where the derivative can come from. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: $\mathbb E[(X-\mu)g(x)]$ = g(x)E[X-\mu]=0 since $E[X] = \mu$. Please revise the title and first sentence of your question to make sure that it matches what you are really wanting to know.

Comment: If $g(x)$ is deterministic then it jumps out of the expectation value by linearity. Do you mean $g(X)$ or something similar?

Comment: Try integration by parts: $E[(X-\mu)g(X)] = \int g(x)\frac{ (x-\mu)}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}{\rm d}x = \sigma^2\int g'(x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}{\rm d}x = \sigma^2E[g'(x)]$.

Comment: Sorry, yes it was meant to be $g(X)$. @Winther Thank you very much!

Comment: Basically remember that $f'=-xf$ for pdf of a standard normal.

Comment: Thank you all for your help